# Why do I have a deadlock?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have tried to recreate a situation below, wherein I am trying to run three functions concurrently. However, I can only run the second and third function after a certain point in the first function, since it depends on a value from the first function. For this case, I used a channel. Here's my code:

```
package code
import "fmt"

func First(c chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        continue
    }
    test := "test"
    fmt.Println(test)
    c <- test
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        fmt.Print(i)
    }
}

func Second(c chan string) {
    msg:= <- c
    fmt.Println(msg)
    if msg != "" {  // I need to run the whole of First before running second and third concurrently then
        fmt.Println("second", msg)
        for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
            fmt.Print(i)
        }
    }
}

func Third(c chan string) {
    msg:= <- c
    fmt.Println("third", msg)
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        fmt.Print(i)
    }
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "./code"
    "fmt"
    "sync"

    //"sync"
    "time"
)
func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)
    var c chan string = make(chan string)
    go func() {
        code.First(c)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        code.Second(c)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        code.Third(c)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    end := time.Now()
    delta := end.Sub(start)
    fmt.Println("time", delta.Seconds())
}
```

Currently, I am getting a deadlock. A couple extra questions- is there a way to first check the values given by the channel, and if they are not certain expected values I first complete running the first function and then run second and third concurrently? Essentially a check like the one I added in second? If it is the expected value I'd like all the functions to run concurrently after the channel gets particular values from the first function.

Answer (score 2):

Your main program spawns off three extra goroutines, and then waits for all three to signal (via `wg.Done`) that they are done.  All three goroutines, plus `main` itself, share one channel over which you can send one `string` instance at a time (and which you use to send exactly one).

One goroutine (which calls `code.First`) spins for a bit and then sends a string.  Once the string is sent, that goroutine prints many numbers, then signals done-ness and quits.

Two other goroutines (which call `code.Second` and `code.Third`) immediately block waiting to receive a string.  Depending on precisely when they run and the vagaries of who gets the string, *one* of them will get the string that `code.First` sends.  The other remains blocked.

Whichever one gets a string (which is currently always `"test"`), that one then prints its name and many numbers, then signals done-ness and quits.

Whichever one *didn't* get a string is still waiting for a string.  Meanwhile, the `wg.Wait` in `main` is waiting for the last `wg.Done` call, which can no longer occur as all remaining goroutines are waiting (there are now just these two—`main` and whichever *didn't* get the string—left).  This is your deadlock.

It looks as though you expected *both* goroutines to receive the string that was sent from `code.First`.  That does not happen: one of them gets the string, and the other continues waiting.  (There is no promise as to *who* gets the string.)

> A couple extra questions- is there a way to first check the values given by the channel ...

Sure: whatever string you get, you have a string.  You can do whatever operation you like with it, just as you already compare it to `""`.

> ... and if they are not certain expected values I first complete running the first function and then run second and third concurrently

That's just a Small Matter Of Programming.  If you wish to be able to control *who* gets *which* message(s), though, you'll need one channel per receiving goroutine.  If you make two separate channels, `code.First` can take both, and can send an appropriate message to either additional goroutine at whatever point you like.